# changing uifont color in a table cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i am trying to change the color of the cell using the following code, however it displays all the cell's as white font instead of the gold rgb color code i have.

```
if (row == 0)

    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"An blah blah";
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:139 green:136 blue:120 alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 4):

You're setting it on the wrong label, this should work:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"An blah blah";
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:139/255.0f green:136/255.0f blue:120/255.0f alpha:1];
```

Comment: thanks i had the correct labels in my app, i just rewrote them wrong here sorry but thanks for the division by 255 tip

Answer (score 1):

The RGB parameters are in the range 0 to 1.
Divide your 0-255 values by 255.

```
if (row == 0)
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"An blah blah";
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:139/255.0f green:136/255.0f blue:120/255.0f alpha:1];
```

Also, maybe you meant detailTextLabel.textColor instead of textLabel.textColor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure  you did if to the sake of the example but you should use

```
if (indexPath.row == 0){
   cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"detailed text";  
   cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:139/255.0f green:136/255.0f blue:120/255.0f alpha:1]; 
   return;
}
```